# IDE CodeLite displays an error when debugging project(during startup program exited with code 0xc0000135)

Tags: c++, mingw, codelite

**IDE CodeLite** displays an error when debugging project

> during startup program exited with code 0xc0000135

- **IDE**: CodeLite
- **Compiler**: Mingw

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are linking the libraries correctly?

Comment: @macroland 
No, I'm not sure

Comment: If you are using Window make sure the bin path of MinGW is in your Environmental Variables of Windows.

Comment: @macroland How to do it?

Comment: @macroland  I posted image. That's what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

- reinstall `mingw`.
- Add the path to the environmental parameters in the system.
- try again.